# send .doc file as an attachment to mail

Tags: android

i want to send a .doc file as an attachment via email.

i am using the code below:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

                        emailIntent.putExtra(
                                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                "Song Pad.");

                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                "Please see the attached document.");

                        final File file = new File(dirPath + "/" + filename
                                + ".doc");
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));

                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                                emailIntent, "Send Email..."));
```

the attachment goes successfully to email but when i open it on device it shows message

**Unable to find viewer for plain/text**.

on the other hand when i send doc file not via my app then it opens perfectly.

please guide . i think there is little mistake..
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a mime type of .doc documents `application/msword`.

Comment: i'll have to use emailIntent.setType("application/msword");

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.fromFile(file);
```